# How to remove DoubleQuotes from String extracted from Service Data using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, web-services, arraylist, spinner

i am gettig data from Service and after removing 
 from data i have in this format.

i have saved data in an array like this:

> String data array(24150): 1,"product group","12345","Service Spares"
>
> String data array(24150): 2,"product group","12345","No Longer In Use"
>
> String data array(24150): 3,"product group","12345","Door Entry"

**now i want to extract String **product group** from this array if my already initialized string is equal to product group then save  text in an array list after last ,(comma) without double quotes.Here is the code but its returning me ""  how can i remove double quotes please guide me...**.

```
    for(int i=0;i<spinnerDataArraylocal.length;i++)
        {
          Log.i("String data array",""+spinnerDataArraylocal[i]);
           int index1 = spinnerDataArraylocal[i].indexOf(",");
         String labelString = spinnerDataArraylocal[i].substring(index1+1,spinnerDataArraylocal[i].indexOf(",",index1+1));
        Log.i("first comma position:",""+labelString);
        if(labelString.equals("\"Premises Type\""))
         {   int index = spinnerDataArraylocal[i].lastIndexOf(",");
             Log.i("string compare","labelString" + labelString);
             Log.i("extrACT STRING:" , spinnerDataArraylocal[i].substring(index+1));
             String sample = spinnerDataArraylocal[i].substring(index+1);
             Log.i("sample",""+sample);
             premisesTypeArrayList.add(sample.toString().trim());
             Log.i("premisesTypeArrayList",""+premisesTypeArrayList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPremisesType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_spinner,
                    premisesTypeArrayList);
            adapterPremisesType.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_item_list);
 spinnerPremisesType.setAdapter(adapterPremisesType);
spinnerPremisesType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
  View view, int position, long id) {

   }
  @Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  }
 });
adapterPremisesType.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

i need to reWrite this code as :   `if(labelString.equals("Premises Type"))` instead of this

```
if(labelString.equals("\"Premises Type\""))
```

here is how my dropdown data is filling which should be without double quotes and spaces

[image: DROPDOWN IMAGE]

Comment: can you post you hole text which you are getting?

Comment: my whole text is quite large cant post here it contains <br/> tag i have separated them from <br/>

Comment: but for this type of data this is not right way to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this `string =string.replaceAll("\"", "");`

The split code below.

```
String string = "41,\"Premises Type\",\"A\",\"Retail\"";        
string =string.replaceAll("\"", "");
String[] array =string.split(",");
System.out.println(array[0]);
System.out.println(array[1]);
System.out.println(array[2]);
System.out.println(array[3]);
```

Your complete code look like this

```
for(int i=0;i<spinnerDataArraylocal.length;i++)
{
        String spinData = spinnerDataArraylocal[i];
        spinData = spinData.replaceAll("\"", "");
        String spinData[] = spinData.split(",");
        if(spinData[1].trim().equals("Premises Type"))
        {   
            String sample = spinData[1]+","+spinData[2]+","+spinData[3];
            premisesTypeArrayList.add(sample.toString().trim());            
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPremisesType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_spinner,
                    premisesTypeArrayList);
            adapterPremisesType.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_item_list);
            spinnerPremisesType.setAdapter(adapterPremisesType);
            spinnerPremisesType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,  View view, int position, long id) {

                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }
            });
            adapterPremisesType.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

complete code for you

```
public class Tets  {


   public static void main(String [] args) {
       String  data  = "3,\"product group\",\"12345\",\"Door Entry\"";        
       String [] items =data .split(",");
       System.out.println(items[0]);
       System.out.println(items[1].substring (1,items[1].length()-1));
       System.out.println(items[2].substring (1,items[2].length()-1));
       System.out.println(items[3].substring (1,items[3].length()-1));
   }


}
```

good luck